# Delete product by product_id in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete the product from database by passing id in delete button. Instead of respective product_id, the value is passing like as first product id 1 is deleted and then 2. The product which i want to delete is not passing id for deleting. The form is in post method

```
<td><?php echo $product['product_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['product_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['product_category']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['minbid_price']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product['end_time']; ?></td>
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
<td><button type="submit" name="btn_delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

The code in delete.php is below which is showing result of the query at the moment.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_delete'])){
//Get form data
 $delete_id = $_POST['product_id'];

 echo $delete_id;
```

Comment: Why don't u just use `$delete_id = $_POST['btn_delete'];`?

Comment: Note that in general, it's unusual to want to permanently delete information from a database, unless there's a legal requirement to do so.

Comment: Use GET parameter which will be product id ?

Comment: where is the form tag? can see the details?

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee. Your idea of ans helped me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use  **form** tag:

```
...
<form action="delete.php">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
<td><input type="submit" name="btn_delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"/></td>
</form>
...
```

**delete.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['product_id'])){
 $delete_id = $_POST['product_id'];

 echo $delete_id;
 }
```

Comment: Missing is not the correct word. As `op` probably has multiple hidden fields with the name `product_id` in 1 form, it is a solution to split it up in one form for each product otherwise the `product_id` will always be overridden by the last input with the name `product_id`

Comment: @DarkBee thank you for extending my answer, I agree with you